# Why is the loop not breaking?

Tags: c++, loops, menu, switch-statement, infinite

I wrote this simple menu that runs until I choose to quit. Each choice function just displays the message that it was chosen. Each function is placed in a switch statement that is in a while (true) loop. It is supposed to break after a function runs once but I am getting infinite loop. I have tried it with else if statements and it worked properly. I want to use switch because it looks clean and easy to manage. Please tell me the logic error and I will fix it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>


bool validation(int testChoice, int minC, int maxC, std::string message)
{
    bool invalid = false;

    if ((std::cin.fail())|| (testChoice >maxC) || (testChoice < minC))
    {
        std::cout << message <<std::endl;
        invalid = true;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
    }
    return invalid;
}

int menu()
{
   bool flag = true;
   int testChoice;
   int minC = 1, maxC = 8;
   do
   {
        std::cout <<"Which test to run?: \n";
        std::cout <<"1.  Test1 \n";
        std::cout <<"2.  Test2 \n";
        std::cout <<"3.  Test3 \n";
        std::cout <<"4.  Test4 \n";
        std::cout <<"5.  Test5 \n";
        std::cout <<"6.  Test6 \n";
        std::cout <<"7.  test7 \n";
        std::cout <<"8.  Quit \n";
        std::cout <<"Pick one: ";
        std::string message = "1-8 only: ";
        std::cin >> testChoice;
       flag = validation(testChoice, minC, maxC, message);
   }
   while(flag);
   return testChoice;
}
void test1()
{
    std::cout <<"Test 1 was chosen\n";
}
void test2()
{
    std::cout <<"Test 2 was chosen\n";
}
void test3()
{
    std::cout <<"Test 3 was chosen\n";
}
void test4()
{
    std::cout <<"Test 4 was chosen\n";
}
void test5()
{
    std::cout <<"Test 5 was chosen\n";
}
void test6()
{
    std::cout <<"Test 6 was chosen\n";
}
void test7()
{
    std::cout <<"Test 7 was chosen\n";
}
int toRun(int testChoice) //Pass in the return value from menu
{
   while (true)
   {

    switch(testChoice)
    {
        case 1:
        test1();
        break;

        case 2:
        test2();
        break;

        case 3:
        test3();
        break;

        case 4:
        test4();
        break;

        case 5:
        test5();
        break;

        case 6:
        test6();
        break;

        case 7:
        test7();
        break;
        case 8:
        return 0;

    }
   }
}
int main ()
{
    int choice = menu();
    toRun(choice);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't ask for new input inside your `while (true)`, so it will never hit the `return` statement, unless it's initially given `8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't ask for new input inside your `while (true)`, so it will never hit the `return` statement, unless it's initially given `8`. To fix this, simply update the `testChoice` variable inside the loop. A possible solution would be:

```
int toRun() // No parameter needed now
{
   while (true)
   {
       int testChoice = menu();
       switch(testChoice)
       {
           …
```

If you want it to only ever run once, then remove the `while` loop entirely.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I will update my code. I forgot to place the menu in a loop oops.

Answer (score 3):

Note that a `break` inside `switch` will break the switch only, not your entire `while` loop!

The switch statement breaks after executing a testcase but the loop continues because it's condition is `true` and there is no break or return statement elsewhere, except for a `return` in `case 8`. That's the only case where your code will work properly.

> I have tried it with else if statements and it worked properly.

That's because a `break` in this scenario will break your `while` loop instead of breaking a `case` as in the case of a switch statement.

**Solution:**

Remove that while-loop altogether, and keep only the contents inside it. You don't need a loop there, actual looping is happening inside the menu (that do-while loop). Also, add appropriate return statements to each case. Currently, only `case 8` has a return statement. Moreover, I don't see you using the return value of `toRun`. You can also just make it `void` and avoid those return statements altogether.